# File QtGui4.dll missing

Tags: beamer, errors, compiling

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and want to prepare presentation in beamer.
My Latex works nornally when writing articles, however when trying using

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\end{document}
```

I am obtaining information that the QtGui4.dll is missing from my computer, how to fix this issue?
My operation system is Windows 8.1

Will be grateful for the advice!

Comment: Such a nice MWE ...

Comment: I cannot verify that on my Mac. +1 because it looks interesting. (If it is not off-topic)

Comment: Do other document classes work?

Comment: Yes, rest of classes are working. However, sometimes the problem arises when trying to use some packages, but I was using alternatives. Now however, I would like to resolve this issue.